# Angular 6 How to implement canActivateChild

Tags: angular, angular-guards

I'm new to Angular auth guard. I have successfully integrated auth guard so that logged in users can access the private pages. For this, I used `CanActivate`. Now, my intention is to use another type of guard which prevent the logged in users to access some of the private pages. 
From https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-route-guards-canactivate-and-canactivatechild-example, I came to know that I can use `canActivateChild` to achieve the similar result.

In `app-routing.module.ts` file I used the below:

```
const routes: Routes = [ ...
{ path: 'myaccount', loadChildren: '../module/myaccount/myaccount.module#MyAccountModule',canActivate: [AuthGuard] },...];
```

Under the `myaccount` component, I have several other child component.

In `myaccount-routing.module.ts`, I wrote this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
...
{ path: 'abc', component: AbcComponent,
    children: [
    { path: 'xyz', component: XyzComponent, canActivateChild: [ AuthGuard ] },
... ]
   }
];
```

In the `abc` component under `myaccount` I wrote the following within the `abc-routing.module.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
...
{ path: 'xyz', component: XyzComponent, canActivateChild: [ AuthGuard ]},
...
];
```

This is my `auth.guard.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild} from '@angular/router';
import { CommonService } from './../services/common.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  private userData:any={};

    constructor(
        private router: Router,  
        private commService : CommonService
    ) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    ...
    }
    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    console.log("fired!);
    return true;
    }
}
```

When I go to the xyz page from browser say `myaccount/abc/xyz`, it should fire the browser console however, I can't see any text in browser console. There is no error in the CLI too. I refreshed the `xyz` page however, no luck. No text in the browser console. Any idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I know that "CanActivateChild" cannot be used for a single child route/path. It will protect the entire children routes under a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you providing `AuthGuard`?, from the example its not provided at root. You can change that to `@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})`

**EDIT**

Take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-canactivatechild-example), it looks like the `canActivateChild` is triggered when it has a parent `canActivate`. If you need to perform a validation on a specific page you should add another `canActivate` on the page you wish to secure

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have used your code in my `auth.guard.ts` however, it does not work. My question is how can prevent a single child item through canActivateChild. See the myaccount-routing.module.ts file. Under myaccount path, there are several children but I want to prevent one path say xyz by canActivateChild.